# PNG file has invalid signature

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm working on panoramic image stitching and in imread function i got format error:PNG file has invalid signature.I googled it but i did not find anything.Can you explain me reason of error?

EDIT: baseInputPath+path=Input/PanoramaImage30/image1.png

```
baseInputPath='Input/'
baseOutputPath='Output/'

def imread(path='in.png'):
    '''reads a PNG RGB image at baseInputPath+path and return a numpy array organized along Y, X, channel.
    The values are encoded as float and are linearized (i.e. gamma is decoded)'''
    global baseInputPath
    print baseInputPath+path
    reader=png.Reader(baseInputPath+path)
    im=reader.asFloat()
    a=numpy.vstack(im[2])
    if im[3]['greyscale']:
        raise NameError( 'Expected an RGB image, given a greyscale one')        
    x, y=im[0], im[1]
    a.resize(y, x, 3)
    a**=2.2
    return a
```

Comment: Probably one of your PNG files is corrupted or not a PNG file at all. Can you open it in an image viewer?

Comment: Thanks for comment.At the begining i converted jpeg files to png so files corrupted.Now reconverted it and working with success.

Answer (score 0):

At the begining i converted jpeg files to png so files corrupted.Now reconverted it and working with success.